# Limit of function defined as $|f(x)-f(y)|<K|x-y|$

Tags: calculus, limits, lipschitz-functions

I'm looking for a hint on how to solve the following problem:

if $f$ is a function satisfying the following property:
There exists a constant $K\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le K|x-y|$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ and knowing that $f(2)=7$, then what is $\lim_{x\rightarrow2 }f(x)$?

Comment: Set $y=2$ and the property becomes $|f(x)-f(2)|<K|x-2|$. For any given $\epsilon>0$ if you take $\delta=\epsilon/K$, then if $|x-2|<\delta$, it follows that $|f(x)-f(2)|\leq K|x-2|<\epsilon$. This is the definition that $\lim_{x\to2}f(x)=f(2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $f$ is $K$-Lipschitz, so it's continuous.

$$\lim_{x\to 2}f(x) = f(2) = 7$$